# How to not exit a conversation after account linking?

Tags: actions-on-google

When testing my app in the Simulator using a Speaker (e.g. Google Home), it always says "'MyApp' left the conversation" after successfully linking. Here is an example:

1. User signs up via the web site that I created for MyApp (i.e. they have an account associated with their Google email account).
2. User then tries to use MyApp using Google Home by saying "Talk to MyApp". They are greeted with this message:

> Before you can use MyApp, you'll need to be signed in with them. To do
>   that, they'll need some of your info. If you want more details, say
>   "Tell me more. " So, can I share your name, email address, and profile
>   picture with them?

3. User says, "yes" and their account is linked.
4. Google Assistant responds with "Great, they found your account, and they've linked it to Google." That is followed by the line, "'MyApp' left the conversation."

Because MyApp left the conversation in step 4, the user has to say, "Talk to MyApp" once more in order to actually start using the app.

**So my question is, is there a way that I can link the account and not have MyApp leave the conversation automatically?** When my TokenUrl responds back to Google in order to link the account, it can just send token_type, access_token, and expires_in according to the [documenation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth). There doesn't seem to be any other mechanism to tell it to not end the conversation but this seems like something that should be supported.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT#1 to further explain setup**

- I have tried to create an Intent in the Dialogflow console and put "actions_intent_SIGN_IN" (from https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/intents) and set it to be fulfilled by my webhook but this never fires.
- In the Dialogflow console > Integration Settings, under "Explicit Invocation" I have "Welcome" (a.k.a. my Welcome intent that hands the WELCOME and GOOGLE ASSISTANT WELCOME Events. The **Sign in required** checkbox is checked next to this.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot showing the complete Dialogflow configuration for the Sign In intent? Can you also update the question with more information about how you've configured Authentication in the Action console?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your *Action*, not with your OAuth server. It sounds like your Action isn't handling the Intent that reports the sign-in is a success or a request that contains the user's auth token.

Check your logs, including the logs for your webhook, to make sure there are no errors in that stage.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors anywhere and can't find a way to "handle the intent that reports the sign-in as a success." Is it possibly because I have the "Sign in required" checkbox checked? Please see my EDIT#1 in the original post.